# C++ Member Reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++

I'm running into a Problem in my C++ Code.

I have a union `StateValue`:

```
union StateValue
{
    int intValue;
    std::string value;
};
```

and a struct `StateItem`

```
struct StateItem
{
    LampState state;
    StateValue value;
};
```

I have a method which goes through a vector of type `StateItem`

```
for(int i = 0; i < stateItems.size(); i++)
{
    StateItem &st = stateItems[i];
    switch (st.state)
    {
        case Effect:
            result += std::string(", \"effect\": ") + st.value.value;
            break;
        case Hue:
            result += std::string(", \"hue\": ") + st.value.intValue.str();
            break;
        case On:
            result += std::string(", \"on\": ") + std::string(st.value.value);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In the case `Hue` I get the following Compiler error:

```
Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union
```

I can´t understand the problem here.
Can anyone of you please help me?

Comment: `int` doesn't have a `str()` function. It's not even a class.

Comment: Note that being able to use non-pod types (like `std::string`) in  unions is new with [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), so if you try to compile it with older compilers that doesn't support C++11 then you will get an error.

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to look at the function [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: This error msg is also given by the compiler if one writes something like this:
A a;
int a = a.FunctionThatReturnsInt();

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're trying to call a member function on `intValue`, which has type `int`. `int` isn't a class type, so has no member functions.

In C++11 or later, there's a handy `std::to_string` function to convert `int` and other built-in types to `std::string`:

```
result += ", \"hue\": " + std::to_string(st.value.intValue);
```

Historically, you'd have to mess around with string streams:

```
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << st.value.intValue;
    result += ", \"hue\": " + ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union`

`int` is a primitive type, it has no methods nor properties.

You are invoking `str()` on a member variable of type `int` and that's what the compiler is complaining about.

Integers cannot be implicitly converted to string, but you can used `std::to_string()` in C++11, `lexical_cast` from `boost`, or the old-slow approach of the `stringstream`.

```
std::string to_string(int i) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}
```

or

```
template <
    typename T
> std::string to_string_T(T val, const char *fmt ) {
    char buff[20]; // enough for int and int64
    int len = snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), fmt, val);
    return std::string(buff, len);
}

static inline std::string to_string(int val) {
    return to_string_T(val, "%d");
}
```

And change the line to:

```
result += std::string(", \"hue\": ") + to_string(st.value.intValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your intvalue is no object. It has no member functions. You could use sprintf() or itoa() to convert it to a string.

Comment: In C++ speak, an instance of an `int` is an object.

Comment: The standard (c++11) way is to use `std::to_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

`intValue` is an `int`, it has no methods.